# I'm no simple weed for you to pull

Tags: riddle

> I'm no simple weed for you to pull,
>
> My roots as strong as when I was whole.
>
> Great fields of my brothers are mankind's shame,
>
> And when you give up you'll hear my name.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is:

> Tree Stump

I'm no simple weed for you to pull,
My roots as strong as when I was whole.

> It is not easy to uproot a tree stump.

Great fields of my brothers are mankind's shame,

> Deforestation is sad.

And when you give up you'll hear my name.

> Man, I am... "Stumped"!

Comment: So close! Matt was just a second earlier than you.

Comment: Ah that's strange, it shows mine as being 13 seconds quicker on the time stamp! Good riddle though!

Comment: Is there a way to see the exact time stamp? I was assuming he was first because he was first in the list when I pulled up the page and you both had the same number of votes.

Comment: When you mouse over the "answered 5 mins ago" text, it shows the stamp. I won't quibble over who gets the credit though!

Comment: Ah, I see... well, you were actually 13 seconds faster.

Comment: @Cameron you can also right-click the grey relative time text and select "Inspect Element". It will show the ISO timestamp in the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> Stump

Reasoning:

I'm no simple weed for you to pull,

> Stumps are not easy to remove from the ground

My roots as strong as when I was whole.

> The tree is no longer whole, having been cut down. Yet the roots remain strong.

Great fields of my brothers are mankind's shame,

> Lots of stumps indicate mass deforestation (capitalism, lack of care for the environment. etc.).

And when you give up you'll hear my name.

> When you give up, you're "stumped".

Comment: Yep, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

"I'm no simple weed for you to pull,"

> I'm no simple "weed" to get rid of. In other words, I will always be around, no matter how hard you try to get rid of me, much more pesky than a weed.

"My roots as strong as when I was whole"

> My roots through mankind are as powerful currently as they were when I was "whole", i.e. maybe a human myself?...

"Great fields of my brothers are mankind's shame"

> My brothers are those who die each day and buried in "great fields" known as cemeteries, usually from the shameful harm mankind inflicts on each other.

"And when you give up, you'll hear my name"

> When you give up raging against "the dying of the light", you will hear my name, which is death.

Therefore, I am guessing you are...

> Death

Comment: Interesting thoughts, but that's not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about...

> Oddish

*I'm no simple weed for you to pull*

> It's a Pokemon, not just any weed!

*My roots as strong as when I was whole.*

> The implication being you accidentally pulled a leaf off

*Great fields of my brothers are mankind's shame,*

> They're so common, it's really a shame someone would go through the effort of breeding them so often, they're not even that great.

*And when you give up you'll hear my name.*

> Pokemon cries consist of the pokemon's name. If you stop pulling on it, it will cry *"Oddish!"*